# ngFor multidimensional json object

Tags: angular, loops, object, ngfor

I have my angular application calling an external API which returns a JSON string of products.

The `productService` makes a simple API call:

```
getProducts() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/getProducts', this.config)
}
```

My component subscribes the data to a variable:

```
AllProducts: Object;
ProductGroups: Object;

constructor(private _product: ProductService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._product.getProducts().subscribe(data = > {
        this.AllProducts = data;
        this.ProductGroups = Object.keys(data);
        console.log("Got Products");
        console.log(this.AllProducts);
        console.log(this.ProductGroups);
    })
}
```

The Json string looks like:

```
{\"Product1\": {\"P1-1\": {\"productType\": \"Test\", \"productStatus\": \"In Stock\", \"productTitle\": \"Product1 Test Product\", \"productDescription\": \"First test product1\"}}, \"Product2\": {\"P2-1\": {\"productType\": \"Test\", \"productStatus\": \"In Stock\", \"productTitle\": \"Product2 test product 1\", \"productDescription\": \"The first product of group 2\"}, \"P2-2\": {\"productType\": \"Test\", \"productStatus\": \"Out of Stock\", \"productTitle\": \"Product2 test product 2\", \"productDescription\": \"Second product of group 2\"}}}
```

The Browser console output for `AllProducts` looks like:

```
Object {
Product1: Object {
"P1-1": Object { productType: "Test"
 ...
```

My HTML uses nested `*ngFor`s to try and render anything on the page:

```
<div *ngfor='let productGroup of ProductGroups'>
   <h2>{{productGroup}}</h2>
   <ul>
      <li *ngfor="let item of AllProducts['productGroup']">
         {{item}}
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The `<h2>` renders the product group names correctly, but I have not been able to list any of the product details.

Edit:

I have control over the API as well if it is easier to tweak the JSON string.

I should also mention that it is currently on Angular 6.0.0 and I have not been able to get it to work on 6.1.0 or any other versions yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description) *(available in angular 6.1)* for this:

```
<div *ngFor='let productGroup of AllProducts | keyvalue'>
    <h2>{{productGroup.key}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of productGroup.value | keyvalue">
        {{item.key}}
         <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let innerItem of item.value | keyvalue">
                  {{innerItem.key}}: {{innerItem.value}}
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I tried this I got an error in the console: `ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found (...` Just reading the link posted now.

Comment: The KeyValue Pipe is available in angular 6.1

Comment: Ah, that would be it. I inherited the project and it is currently 6.0.0. I tried upgrading it to 8 and the entire thing broke. I will try upgrading it to 6.1

Comment: @an00b, if you didn't know, you can follow Angular's [official update guide here](https://update.angular.io/). It'll guide you step by step what you need to change for each version of upgrade. I think it's better to upgrade version by version. I.e. from Angular 6 => Angular 7 => Angular 8.

Comment: Thanks @terahertz I followed this to go from 6 to 8 and I think too many dependencies broke. I managed to upgrade to 6.1 and got `KeyValue` to work.